# SharePoint most clicked links

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I am trying to make a web part that will display what links got clicked/viewed the most across the whole site collection. These links come from a SharePoint list.

Is there a mechanism in the object model that can be used to accomplish this?

Any thought would be helpful.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?  Do you need it to be in a web part or do you just need to get the statistics?

Comment: I am using MOSS 2007. I am going to use display the info in a web part as "Videos Being Watched Now" on YouTube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the links all go to SharePoint pages within your portal, then you might be able to gather the information in your Site Usage Report, then query that in a custom web part. If the links point to places outside your portal, I am not aware of any out-of-the-box record of which links are getting clicked on in a SharePoint list. You could possibly make some javascript to add special code to the list interface so that, whenever a link is clicked, it first records to a database, then takes the user to the destination.